# Align specific inline li to center of ul

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

I have this html structure

```
<div class="top_menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="left"><a href="" class="family-filter">asdas</a></li>
        <li class="welcome">Welcome <span class="username">Guest</span></li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this css code:

```
.top_menu { 
  padding: 20px; background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.top_menu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0; }
.top_menu ul li { display: inline; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid red; }
.top_menu ul .welcome { text-align:center; }
.top_menu ul li a { font-size: 14px; }
```

I am trying to align `.welcome` to middle of `.top_menu > ul`. I've tried the above and this:

`.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}`

but no success, any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/U2mfK/

Comment: Try `display:block;margin:0 auto !important;`

Comment: thanks Ben, but that won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `.welcome` before you are defining the global styles for the `li`. This will mean any styles in the `.top_menu ul li` will override the styles in the .welcome (display:block;). Put it below like this:

```
.top_menu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0; }
.top_menu ul li { display: inline; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid red; }
.top_menu ul .welcome { text-align:center; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
.top_menu ul li a { font-size: 14px; }
```

**UPDATE**

By positioning the outside `li` tags absolutely, you are able to prevent them from pushing the center `li` off center.

Like this (I have only included the additional styles for clarity):

```
.top_menu ul { position: relative; }
.top_menu ul .left { position: absolute; left: 0; }
.top_menu ul .welcome { text-align:center; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
.top_menu ul .right { position: absolute; right: 0; }
```

Alternatively, you could leave the `.left` and `.right` as they are with their floats, and just position the center element absolutely like this:

```
.top_menu ul { position: relative; }
.top_menu ul .left { float: left; }
.top_menu ul .welcome { text-align:center; display: block; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -100px; width: 200px; }
.top_menu ul .right { float: right; }
```

**If you use the above method, make sure `margin-left` is half the width. You MUST specify a width for this method. If you just make it larger than content, it will center the content because of the `text-align: center` so this should not be a problem**

Comment: that was just a test, either way it won't go.

Comment: Change inline-block to just block

Comment: Answer edited, the reason why it is not in the center is to do with the float left. Add a border to all of the elements and try to debug it from there. I'll have a look at it now

Comment: I take that back, I think you have set a width to the box and not aligned it to the center. Try aligning the text of the `.welcome` to center and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Make the float elements absolutely positioned with top:0 and left:0/right:0. **Make sure the ul is relatively positioned**

Comment: ok, it did the job but, why the `top:0`... it works without it too

Comment: Sorry, that was just me trying to be helpful, you don't actually need it as it defaults to 0. Is it sorted then? I will update my answer

Answer (score 3):

`text-align: center;` needs to be set to the parent. So move it from `.welcome` to `.top_menu ul` :)

Comment: You are correct. It seems as it centers the item in the available space. So if your left-floated element is wider than your right-floated, the centered element will go to your right :(

Comment: Any possible solutions you can think of?